# Can 'to think' be an ordinary monotransitive verb?

Tags: grammaticality, phrasal-verbs

(Per p  78, *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* (2005), by Huddleston & Pullum)
 'ordinary monotransitive' means this structure:
Subject-Predicate-Direct Object-Predicative Complement.

[Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z8zGpbpwRhIC&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=%22something+than+which%22&source=bl&ots=SrrmlntwoJ&sig=y2xUWPE94VkE_b5MXn2LAMxIVTg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwA2oVChMIobf79umUxgIVBI0NCh2oZQD9#v=onepage&q=%22something%20than%20which%22&f=false) pp 158-159, *The Cambridge Companion to Anselm*, by Brian Davies, Brian Leftow

> What Anselm describes himself as looking for here[,]
>    he believed he had found[,]
>   when reflecting on the idea that
>   [1.] God is "something than which
>   nothing greater can be **thought**"
>   (*aliquid quo maius nihil cogitari 
>   potest*). This formula appears early in Proslogion 2, and it dominates 
>   the discussion to the end of the work.

The bold looks wrong. Should **thought**  be replaced with a preposition verb or particle verb
(eg **thought ABOUT** or **thought OF**)? 
Why or why not?

To eliminate the relative clause from the sentence, rewrite [1.] as follows:

2. Nothing greater can be **thought** something than God.

[2] is wrong. So how's [1] right?

Afterword: I first encountered this syntax [here](https://courses.edx.org/courses/MITx/24.00_1x/3T2014/courseware/a3af865809bc48d79c4681a861b72f9d/9992a9c0a3884fb7bb1eedb1a0c3ec3f/).

Comment: You're confusing *transitive* and *intransitive*. *Think* is most commonly intransitive (unless you consider *that* clauses objects), but it has had transitive uses for centuries: "I think it likely", "She thinks him a great man", "Think only kind thoughts".

Comment: That translation is horrible to my feeling. It clings to the original Latin sentence just like pupils who translate Latin. I would  translate :  There is nothing greater than God. It is not possible to imagine anything greater. By the way, since CGEL uses  intransitive in a new sense we can actually forget the term intransitive and should create a new one.

Comment: Fill in the blank:  "_________ can be thought greater than God".  (clue: ˥IHIN).  Or can we leave it blank?

Comment: @rogermue: to be fair to the authors, they do refer to it as a "formula". It has been around for a few hundred years in English. The phrase is in amber.

Comment: @rogermue For people used to reading syntactically demanding texts, such as philosophy and law, this is quite an ordinary usage, which is found in many other contexts.